# Django - Custom dashboard view authentication issues

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Django version 1.1.1
I have a custom dashboard view set up to override the django admin
default like:

```
(r'^admin/$', 'dashboard.views.dashboard'),
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

dashboard view authenticates with the @staff_member_required decorator

This has been working fine with all users having superuser permissions
but when trying to login a user with just staff member status (have
tried different permission settings) I am throwing a 500 server error:

```
[Sun Jul 18 12:36:59 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi
(pid=13815): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/......../
_site.wsgi'.
[Sun Jul 18 12:36:59 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most
recent call last):
[Sun Jul 18 12:36:59 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/
home/...../lib/python2.5/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 245, in
__call__
[Sun Jul 18 12:36:59 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response =
middleware_method(request, response)
[Sun Jul 18 12:36:59 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/
home/....../lib/python2.5/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line
26, in process_response
[Sun Jul 18 12:36:59 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]
patch_vary_headers(response, ('Cookie',))
[Sun Jul 18 12:36:59 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/
home/....../lib/python2.5/django/utils/cache.py", line 130, in
patch_vary_headers
[Sun Jul 18 12:36:59 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     if
response.has_header('Vary'):
[Sun Jul 18 12:36:59 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] AttributeError:
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'has_header'
```

I get the same error when user @login_required as well. Any ideas on
this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should clean your browser cookies and logout properly, both in your public logout url and in the admin logout url. I think normal users opens a session and staff users opens another, so is not a good idea to mix both in the same app.